# K&R How is the char array being reset?

Tags: c

In K&R, we are introduced to char arrays to represent strings.

Arrays are passed by reference. From what I understand, we can point to the first element in an array (pointer?). Using the char array `input` without really defining its values means it sets garbage data inside the array. (Honestly not really sure what garbage data is, maybe nulls?).

Anyways, initially the empty char array is passed to function `getLength`, and it sets char array inputs. In my code, I display the `len` and char array `input`.

On the next input, I call `getLength` again, and pass the same char array `input`. I set the values like before and return the length.

How is the old input erased? Aren't I referencing the exact same array that previously stored the previous input? Below my code, I'll show an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000  /* For allocating storage size for char array */

int getLength(char s[]);   /* set char array and return length */

int main(void) {
  int len;
  char input[MAXLINE];

  while ((len = getLength(input)) > 0) {
    printf("len = %d\n", len);
    printf("string = %s", input);
  }
}

int getLength(char s[]) {
  int i, c;

  for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
    s[i] = c;
  }

  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i++] = '\n';
  }

  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;  /* return length including newline */
}
```

Example:

```
Input:  "Hello my name is Philip"
Output: "len = 24"
        "string = Hello my name is Philip"

Input:  "Hi"
Output: "len = 3"
        "string = Hi"
```

When I input "Hi", aren't I using the previous array that has "Hello my name is Philip" stored inside. So won't I expect the array to look like:

```
['H', 'i', '\n', '\0', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'P', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'i', 'p', '\n', '\0', etc...]
```

Edit:

Just to clarify, I understand how `printf("%s", input)` is printing the correct string. I also understand `getLength` will return the correct length every time.

I'm just confused about the chars saved in the array `input`. If we are referencing this same array in memory, how are old chars being handled?

Comment: "From what I understand, arrays have sort of a built-in pointer"

This isn't really correct. In C, an array IS a pointer.

Comment: @mascoj cool, thanks for clarifying. I'll edit to reflect your input

Comment: @mascoj That is incorrect. Arrays are *not* pointers.

Comment: @mascoj you are incorrect. `char a[10]`;  what sizeof(a) returns?

Comment: @EOF I think I remember reading that we point to the first element in the array, right?

Comment: @philipyoo: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
register storage class, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @mascoj There are more. You can't assign the array name. you can have an array of arrays (AKA multidimensional array) and it will have a totally different layout from that of array of pointers. To conclude: Arrays are **not** pointers.

Comment: *"So won't I expect the array to look like..."* Yes, that's exactly what the array looks like. To prove it, try `for(int i=0;i<20;i++) if (input[i]>0x20) putchar(input[i]); else putchar('.');`

Comment: @EOF I should have stated "at runtime, arrays are pointers."

Comment: @mascoj: No, you should not have said incorrect things at all.

Comment: @EOF How is that incorrect? All of those operators are conversions at compile-time.

Comment: @mascoj: Did you read my comment with the standard citation? Did you see a "at runtime, arrays are pointers"? No? Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers. Shocking, I know, for a language to have two loosely related concepts that are not the same.

Comment: Two of three answers are stating: "arrays are pointers" *facepalm*...

Comment: @EOF You wanna not be rude and explain the difference?

Comment: @mascoj C11 draft standard n1570: *An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
particular member object type, called the element type. The element type shall be
complete whenever the array type is specified. Array types are characterized by their
element type and by the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be
derived from its element type, and if its element type is T , the array type is sometimes
called ‘‘array of T ’’. The construction of an array type from an element type is called
‘‘array type derivation’’.*

Comment: @mascoj: Compare and contrast: *A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the
referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T
is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T ’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type is a complete
object type.* Note the absence of "pointers are arrays" or vice versa.

Comment: @EOF Okay so what I may be stuck on is "an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object " as you quoted above......

Comment: in C, when the code references an array name, the array name degrades to a pointer to the first byte in memory of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is the old input erased? Aren't I referencing the exact same array
>   that previously stored the previous input?

The old input is not *erased*. In each iteration of the loop, you are just overwriting the same array `input` and is freshly zero terminated (`s[i] = '\0';`) by `getLength()` in each iteration.

Since you are printing the string *before* the next iteration, it makes it possible to reuse the same array (and overwrite it). So, there really isn't any need to "save" anything.

Comment: I feel sorta stupid. I went ahead and tested the old indexes to see their values, and ya, I saw the old data was still there. Thanks for this post!

Comment: It happens :) As long as you understand it, it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

C arrays are pointers to memory. With the line `char input[MAXLINE];` you have allocated a contiguous block of 1000 bytes. Which are not going to be initialized every time unless you do so explicitly. The junk data you refer to is simply the previous iterations of using this block of bytes.

The end of a char array as a string is usually indicated by the '\0' character. Libraries  that use string i/o like stdio.h make this assumption and calculate length by traversing the string until the zero character is encountered. One possible danger exists when you write nonzero characters all the way to the end of your array and then use strlen from stdio.h to find the length of your string. The function will go beyond the end of the buffer and crash your program.